# Grub can't find grub.cfg file -- Stuck at GRUB Command Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, grub

I am using GPT/UEFI system. I installed KDE Neon and I was using it without any problem since the summer. Then today, I deleted /EFI/ubuntu/ and after I reboot the system, it stuck at grub command line "grub> ".

1- I can boot the system by writing following command to the grub command line

```
configfile (hd0,gpt1)/EFI/neon/grub.cfg
```

2- Also following command works

```
configfile (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

3- Also following command works

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt2)/boot
normal
```

4- I tried followings to fix by booting the system but non of them works

```
- boot-repair program
- update-grub
- apt install --reinstall grub-efi && update-grub
```

So this is the situation. How can I fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is *software development*, not operating system configuration and management. In the future, consider [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) for this class of question -- or, more generically, [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Oh my bad. I'll be more careful next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just fixed the problem!

1. I boot the system manually by entering command to grub> command line. (one of the command that I mentioned in the question)
2. I opened a terminal.
3. `cd /boot/efi/EFI`
4. `cp -r ./neon ./ubuntu`
5. Reboot and it works fine.

I think the problem is specific for KDE Neon because it gave me exactly same problem when I installed it to a new computer. Grub is not looking inside the "/EFI/neon" directory. Instead, it is looking inside "/EFI/ubuntu" but cannot find it so it causes problem.

BTW, the reason I named new folder as "ubuntu" is that KDE Neon is Ubuntu based.

Comment: self answers are good for SO, thanks

Comment: awesome !! I did it on a kali system that was equally broken, just do `cp -r ./kali ./debian`

Comment: I'm curios, how did you find it ?

Comment: I just used my logic. I'm happy that you fixed the problem!

Comment: Sudo update grub from the terminal if you do manage to make it to the gui that will update any modifications to grub.cfg, this method is best if modifications where made to grub from within the os and have not rebooted yet